# Alternative for break operation in scala

Tags: scala

I want to create something like below in scala.

I am writing it in c, but i want to do exactly same in scala.

```
int bool = 0,i,j;
for(j=0;j<5;j++){
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        if(i==3)
           bool=1;
           break;
    }
    if(bool==0)
        continue;
    some function....
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of that `continue` statement? It's the end of the outer for-loop anyway, so it's always going to continue.

Comment: No actually after continue statement there is some function I am calling

Comment: Why not just write the inner loop as `for(i=0;i<=3<;i++)`?

Comment: Its just example. In my code there is other variable which keeps on changing in every loop and `i` is compared with that function.

Comment: Just throw exceptions and handle them. That is the supposed scala way for breaking loops

Comment: You need to express all of this in your code sample. It changes what you're asking for significantly.

Comment: @Zoltán give me some time.. I will edit this post and come up with actual problem.. Thanks for reply :)

Comment: I got the answer.. I can use exist method which will give the same output as I want

Answer (score 3):

In Scala the preferred way is to use methods of the Standard Library and no clearly supported, good way to break out of functions.

An option to achieve the result wished is to use `takeWhile` . If some side effecting logic is wished that can be applied by using `foreach`. An additional  check can for example be introduce by introducing a `predicate`.

The given example code could be improved by using the predicate in a filter, but I think one gets the basic idea.

## Define the functions

```
def someFunction(x: Int): Unit = if ( predicate(x)) println(x)
def predicate : (Int) => Boolean = _ % 2 == 0

(0 to 5).takeWhile(_ != 3) foreach someFunction
```

## Example

```
(0 to 5).takeWhile(_ != 3) foreach someFunction
0
2
someFunction: (x: Int)Unit
predicate: Int => Boolean
```

Comment: Thanks for reply..
I actually want to use that bool variable as a decision making variable in next. So using above code how can I achieve that goal?

Comment: @ Andreas thanks for help. Its not actually I want but your answer help me to reach there

Comment: Added the code needed to use the the bool as decission.